# How to fetch the data from different database in single mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm new to mongoose and mongoldb, in my mongoldb, i'm having difference database, say for eg: On my single mongoDB i have 21 dbs and 143 collection. if i want to fetch the data from each database based on the database name coming from api request, i have written the middleware function for each api request which will connect the particular database based on the name, but the problem is mongodb throws error "connections to your cluster(s) have exceeded 500". i don't how to overcome this problem

Comment: With `mongoose` you can change database connection with `useDb()`. You can cache each one by setting the flag `useCache: true`. For more https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-useDb

Comment: thanks lpizzinidev, i used useDb() method it works for me.